# Appropriate word for "refloating" a space vessel?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, lexicon

This very well may just be outside our lexicon at the moment, due to the fact that space travel is extremely limited, but I am looking for the proper terminology to refer to a space vessel that had been rendered a wreck or a derelict, and was repaired and refitted into a workable vessel.  In naval terms, a sunk vessel would be refloated, but that term is awkward to use in space.

Something like reatmosphered fits the context, but it is awkward and not in the lexicon (though its form makes its intent clear, and could be readily used).

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not going to vote to close, but I suggest that you ask this question, somewhat edited, on https://scifi.stackexchange.com/, probably with the Star Trek tag.  I'll bet that Star Trek has the word.  A space vessel that has been wrecked would probably be repaired in space or on a base on a low gravity asteroid or moon.  Getting a badly wrecked ship down through an atmosphere seems dicey.

Comment: I've added the single-word requests tag. Hope that's okay.

Comment: Personally I would understand what is meant better with "repairing" or "refitting" for both a space vessel or a naval vessel.  You won't use the word(s)  outside a paragraph where the that mentions the type of vessel.  (I'd think "re-floating" might only get the ship off the bottom after which it would need to be towed to a repair yard for extensive replacement of hopelessly damaged equipment.)  Just a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ab2 space.stackexchange.com might be a better one.

Comment: How about re-launch?  Rockets launch into space.  Already suggested in an answer.  Given Star Wars and Star Trek as well as space stations and Apollo, how can this not be in the lexicon?

Comment: @ab2: Kindly do not dump random terminology questions on scifi.SE.  Questions like this one, not tied to a specific work, tend to be closed.  You probably could ask this question about *Star Trek* in particular, but that's not just a tag edit, that's a whole different question (because who knows, maybe *Star Wars* uses a totally different phrase from *Star Trek*, and you'd only get the latter).

Comment: Putting a spacecraft into atmosphere is more akin to sinking it than refloating it.

Comment: A derelict or wrecked ship is not necessarily sunk and therefore does not necessarily need to be refloated to be put back into service. Refloating is the remedy for a very specific way in which a vessel may be disabled. Since that specific method of disabling does not really apply to spaceships (they can crash in water and sink to the bottom, but that is very different from the sinking of a ship), there is no word to describe its remedy. I'm glad you got an answer you liked, but I don't think you asked the question you meant to ask.

Comment: [Please read this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Consider **recommission**, which is defined (somewhat obviously)  by oxforddictionaries.com as "commission again".

This sense of "commission", in turn, is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/commission) as

> Bring (something newly produced) into working condition

Comment: Recommissioning doesn't imply that it was ever unserviceable. Many ships that were deemed unnecessary or obsolete are decommissioned, only to be later recommissioned into active service in another role.

Comment: We would say that a ship is refitted and recommissioned. There is no single word that means both.

Comment: Out of all the options, I think this fits the best with what is in the lexicon.  I will probably ask in scifi to see if we can create a word that is better.

Comment: To me, commissioning has a sense of "making official".  A ship is commissioned when it is given a name and added to the navy.  An officer is commissioned when he is given his rank and assignment.  Only a navy could (re)commission a ship, anyway, while "refloating" could be done by anyone, even pirates or scavengers.

Comment: This has been accepted but @Joe is right. This term only applies to naval or official vessels and only applies to their re-entry into crewed service, not their repair to operable condition.

Comment: @Joe [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/commission) (albeit in the British Dictionary section) has "_15. (transitive) to equip and test (a ship) for active service_" and "_16. to make or become operative or operable: the plant is due to commission next year_", neither of which demand a military/navy connection (in contrast, the sense before these: "_14. (transitive) (**military**) to confer a rank on or authorize an action by_" explicitly mark the military connection).

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: Please do not ask this question on scifi.SE unless you have a specific work of fiction (or at least a franchise) in mind.  SciFi does not answer broad questions about the entire genre unless they have a single definitive answer (e.g. "What was the first story in which...?", not "Give me a list of stories in which...").

Answer (score 18):

"Refloating" might actually work. Space is an ocean, after all (at least according to tvtropes) - naval expressions and similes are rather accepted to use, as far as I've observed, at least in the scifi community. Besides, a spaceship could be considered to be floating in space. As a non-native speaker, I don't know how that term relates to willful motion, however.

Comment: It works for vessels that were grounded or held in some form of drydock, but it wouldn't really work in scifi contexts where the vessel continued to 'float' the entire time and was simply refitted to operating condition.

Comment: @ily There may be literalist objections, but this sounds like a good metaphor. We currently use "space walk", despite it being problematic in a literal sense.

Answer (score 12):

I would be inclined to suggest **relaunched**. The first time a spacecraft is sent into space, it is *launched*; if it's recovered and sent into space again, it's launched again - that is, *relaunched*. The term is also used in a maritime context, for ships that have been repaired/refit in drydock, but which were never officially declared unusable/decommissioned.

Comment: Although it's sort of a duplicate answer, I like the explanation given. +1

Comment: It works if the derelict vessel were grounded and then punched back into space. That probably describes all our current space vessels, but it doesn't work for scifi contexts where the vessel continued to float in space and is just being returned to operating condition.

Comment: @Ily *Launch* means merely "set in motion", not necessarily from a dock or the ground. If a derelict craft has been floating in space for a while, activating its engines to engage a course could be considered launching by that description. I'd even argue that to be true for a derelict that's been resting in a stable orbit, which is technically in motion, just not under its own power. It's not quite the same as being adrift in aimless motion, which is the case I'd agree with you on.

Comment: @lly - actually, ***relaunched*** still does work in that context, especially if the craft in question was in the outer-space equivalent of a drydock. I'll concede that it might be a bit iffy in the case where it's just floating there, and you approach it, fix it _in situ_ and put it back in operation, without it ever being towed, enclosed, docked, _et cetera and what-have-you_.

Answer (score 10):

I'd say "**repressurized**" if we're talking about a ship that was repaired in space.  You would only repressurize the crew compartments if all holes/leaks had been repaired and you were ready for a crew to come aboard, so that act would mark a pivotal moment in the recovery process.  If we're talking about a shipwreck or derelict on the surface of a planet, "**relaunched**" or "**re-orbited**" make sense to me.

Comment: This is almost as inappropriate as 'repaint'. A derelict spacecraft needn't have lost pressure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth need a derelict ship have lost the ability to float above water? :)

Comment: I don't think this quite fits.  While a sunken ship is definitely in dire straits, a depressurized space ship may well be otherwise fully functional.

Comment: A depressurized spaceship might be functional, but a non-functional spaceship is unlikely to be pressurized.  @EdwinAshworth sure, we could imagine a fully intact, ready-to-go spaceship with active life support being "derelict", that is, abandoned, but then there's no "recovery" needed.  The operative verb for the OP would be **commandeer** or **steal** in that case, not an analogue of "refloat".

Comment: You could repressurize a space ship that still has broken engines, and is still adrift.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Just as you refloat a derelict ship when it has broken engines - usually to tow it back for repairs/scrapping. Seems like a good analogy to me.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Sure, but why would you?  Answering the OP's question requires some speculation on the context.  If, in his sci-fi world, spaceships never lose pressure because they're the size of planets, "repressurized" makes no sense.  Refloating a ship in our world doesn't refer to a trivial repair (like repainting), nor does it necessarily mean repairs are complete (as in recommissioning), but it does mark a pivotal moment in the recovery process.  We have to make some assumptions about the sci-fi context to guess what an analogous pivotal moment would be for a spaceship.

Comment: @andrew That's true, but again, you could tow a depressurized ship

Comment: @joe Okay, but "refloat" relies on the ship needing to float so that you can move it somewhere to be scrapped or salvaged, or fixed. Unless the OP's setting requires ships to be pressurized to move, I don't feel this has the same connotations.

Answer (score 7):

The current usage of Earth's rather limited spaceship fleet suggests that we "**refly**" or "**re-fly**" them.

https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=spacex+refly&oq=spacex+refly

1. > “[This represents the culmination of 15 years of work at SpaceX to **refly** a rocket booster.](https://www.theverge.com/2017/3/31/15135304/spacex-launch-video-used-falcon-9-rocket-watch)” *- SpaceX CEO Elon Musk*
2. > "[SpaceX Will Try to **Re-Fly** a Rocket Today](http://www.popularmechanics.com/space/rockets/a25864/spacex-refly-rocket/)" - Popular Mechanics headline

Comment: *Refly* already means "to fly over a previously flown course again". Even if it can be popularized to also mean "send a previously flown vessel on another flight", that doesn't imply the vessel was ever derelict. The SpaceX rocket boosters aren't broken, for that matter - they're (ideally) just refueled and re-fitted with sacrificial parts again (not the same as repairing damage) and are ready for another launch.

Comment: @talrnu Those are good and fair points but this answer is certainly better and better sourced than the currently upvoted responses.

Answer (score 6):

Previously unflyable aircraft that are returned to airworthiness are often described as having been **"Restored."**  This is a bit weak, in that you could restore it cosmetically but still not be able to fly it, so **"Fully Restored"** may be more approriate

For reference see: [Flight of Restored Spitfire](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-cambridgeshire-39220403) and ["fully-restored WWII-era airplanes"](http://www.warhistoryonline.com/war-articles/wwii-airplanes-display.html)

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider a spaceship "space-worthy again" just like a repaired boat is sea-worthy again.

Answer (score 4):

"Salvaged" is a well-used word that is strongly tied to the usage you are asking for, but independent of technology level. Per [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/salvage): "compensation paid for saving a ship or its cargo from the perils of the sea or for the lives and property rescued in a wreck"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Stack Exchange seeks to develop a library of *definitive* answers; this answer would be greatly strengthened by explaining *why* you suggest this word, demonstrating its use with examples, and finding suitable references. Otherwise, it is little more than unsupported personal opinion. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster: on hearing it I immediately understood it fit better than all answers above it.

Answer (score 2):

Reathmosphered would kind of be the antonym, as it is not "returning a space vessel to space faring service", but conversely "pulling it out of space back onto a planet". "Refloating" [reads like a recovery mission](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refloat) to acquire the body of the vessel, and not the reinstating into service itself. That would be a *salvage operation*, or *recovery* in my book. As for repairing a vessel recovered to be spacefairing again, *refitting* or plainly *repairing* it would be generic terms; with a *recommission* (as per [Doug Warren's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/399309/82804)) being a natural consequence.

*Re-fly*" I like as term for placing a planetside-crashed space vessel back in space — but I am not sure in how far it matches "grabbing junk from down here and placing it up there, without being an actually sea/space worthy vessel yet".

(NB: I assume the vessel broke down in space, not planetside; "re-fly" [[Mark Beadles' answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/399310/82804)] would be an excellent word to imply shooting a repaired vessel out of the athmosphere again.)

Answer (score 2):

## It depends.

A depressurized vessel needs to be **repressurized**.

A grounded vessel needs to be **relaunched**.

Such a vessel that wasn't extensively repaired is being **reflown**.

A vessel docked at a spaceport or low-gravity asteroid is **refloated**.

A lost or abandoned vessel is being **salvaged**.

An vessel restored to official service is being **recommissioned**.

The only things that're appropriate for all these contexts are

## **refitted**

and

## **repaired**,

both which you mentioned but neither of which you understood as the correct answer. Maybe you needed to clarify with some more detail about the context?